# How can I extract numbers containing commas from strings in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find all numbers in text and return them in a list of floats.

In the text:

- Commas are used to separate thousands
- Several consecutive numbers are separated by a comma and a space
- Numbers can be attached to words

My code seems to extract numbers separated with a comma and space and numbers attached to words.
However, it extracts numbers separated by commas as separate numbers

```
text = "30feet is about 10metre but that's 1 rough estimate several numbers are like 2, 137, and 40 or something big numbers are like 2,137,040 or something"

list(map(int, re.findall('\d+', text)))
```

The suggestions below work beautifully

Unfortunately, the output of the below returns a string:

```
nums = re.findall(r'\b\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?(?!\d)', text)
print(nums)
```

I need to return the output as a list of floats, with commas between but no speech marks.

```
Eg. 
extract_numbers("1, 2, 3, un pasito pa'lante Maria")
    is [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Unfortunately, I have not yet been successful in my attempts. Currently, my code reads

```
def extract_numbers(text):
  nums = re.findall(r'\b\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?(?!\d)', text)
  
    return (("[{0}]".format( 
                       ', '.join(map(str, nums))))) 

extract_numbers(TEXT_SAMPLE)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try doing a regex `re.findall` search on the following pattern:

```
\b\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?(?!\d)
```

Sample script - [try it here](https://repl.it/@NamG1/extract-numbers-containing-commas)

```
import re

text = "30feet is about 10metre but that's 1 rough estimate several numbers are like 2, 137, and 40 or something big numbers are like 2,137,040 or something"

nums = re.findall(r'\b\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?(?!\d)', text)
print(nums)
```

This prints:

```
['30', '10', '1', '2', '137', '40', '2,137,040']
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
\b            word boundary
\d{1,3}       match 1 to 3 leading digits
(?:,\d{3})*   followed by zero or more thousands terms
(?:\.\d+)?    match an optional decimal component
(?!\d)        assert the "end" of the number by checking for a following non digit
```

Comment: This is perfect answer and should be the accepted one from my view @Hamster

Comment: @NamGVU Only Wiktor Stribiżew's regex is actually perfect `:-)`

Comment: Wiktor Strib who?

Comment: Got him https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew. Thanks any way. We don't need the actual perfect that high ^^

Comment: A less-perfect could be this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63714263/248616 by @RichieV

Comment: @RichieV `(?=\D)` matches any non digit character, _or_ the end of the string.

Comment: @RichieV You indeed caught an edge case (though your original comment did not make it clear).  I have fixed the answer.

Comment: Brilliant, the only problem is we are returning  output as a list and not a string

Comment: Do you want the output as a list or string?  What does this output look like?

Answer (score 1):

Create a pattern with an optional character group `[]`

Code [try it here](https://repl.it/@NamG1/extract-numbers-containing-commas2)

```
import re

text = "30feet is about 10metre but that's 1 rough estimate several numbers are like 2, 137, and 40 or something big numbers are like 2,137,040 or something"

out = [
    int(match.replace(',', ''))
    for match in re.findall('[\d,]+', text)
]
print(out)
```

Output

```
[30, 10, 1, 2, 137, 40, 2137040]
```

Comment: definitely the best approach. gonna save this code. thank u RichieV

Comment: A full-perfect regex match available here by Tim Biegeleisen https://stackoverflow.com/a/63714259/248616

Comment: @NamGVU thanks! His pattern does prevent unexpected use of commas and works also for floats... It was just not required in this case, and I answered because there were no answers at the time... nice link! I didn't know about repl.it

Comment: Glad you like repl - it's a proof for working code in my view.

Comment: This answer has a problem.  The last match is supposed to be `2,137,040`, but your answer is finding `2137040`.  Can you fix this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this answer returns integers, not strings, as it was obviously intended by the OP. The goal of my comments was not to pick a fight, your answer is clearly better. I just noticed that with a different case where the string ended in a digit your answer needed a tiny adjustment.

Comment: If the OP really just wants integers, then this might be the best approach +1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen well I do think that it is good to generalize the solutions, as you did, removing commas and mapping int is trivial, you obviously thought about what would be more useful. Hope there's no hard feelings!

Answer (score 0):

you need to match the commas as well, then strip them before turning them into an integer:

```
list(map(lambda n: int(n.replace(',','')), re.findall('[\d,]+', text)))
```

Also, you should probably be using list comprehensions unless you need python2 compatibility for some reason:

```
[int(n.replace(',', '')) for n in re.findall('[\d,]+', text)]
```

Comment: I was just about to ask you a use case where using `lambda` was the only or best option

Answer (score -1):

y not use?
`array = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', str)`